# How do I change the color of Firefox's menu bar?

Tags: firefox, linux-mint

I upgraded from Linux Mint 16 to 17, and in the process Firefox was upgraded from 30 to 33. Now the text in the menu bar is black, which conflicts with my Firefox theme (that I've been using forever):

[image: The menu labels are black, and so is my theme]

Before, they were the same color as the text on unfocused tabs, but now it's just black. It's ugly and unusable. Restarting Firefox didn't help, and neither did changing themes (well, it's readable on lighter ones, but the text is always black). Why did this happen and how can I fix it? I know I could just switch to a lighter theme, but I've been using this one for so long that using a different one just feels...wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

1. Open your [profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder) (`~/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default` for me)
2. Create a folder called `chrome`, and a file in that folder called `userChrome.css`
3. Put this in that file, changing the color value to whatever you want:

   ```
   /*
   * Do not remove the @namespace line -- it's required for correct functioning
   */
   @namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

    menubar > *{
       color: #8B8B8B !important;
   }
   ```
4. Save the file, then (re)start Firefox.

Unfortunately it will be that color even when you click on it:

[image: It's still gray even when selected]

but I can live with that. It could probably be fixed with better CSS anyway.

Comment: `menubar:hover >*`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some sort of corruption/incompatibility of an add-on. You could try turning off add ons one by one, starting from those that mention styles, or tabs, to see which one is causing this problem.

But, as an alternative solution, I use tab-mix plus 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/
to set the colours of text and tabs. It also provides a multi-row tab bar which I find indispensable.

Comment: Starting Firefox in safe mode (which disables all addons) didn't help. Tab Mix Plus only can only customize tab colors, not the menu bar.